# Convert csv to csv, removing scientific notation from one column

Tags: python, csv, scientific-notation

I'm starting with a CSV exported from a system with 3 columns, the first column is displaying a number in scientific notation. I need to transform only that column to a number and save to another CSV. Note there are thousands of lines, converting using Excel is not an option.

I have found many articles close to this, using "float", using "round", but I haven't found anything that can handle a large file.

Example, file1.csv:

```
ID, Phone, Email
1.23E+15, 123-456-7890, johnsmith@test.com
```

Need the output to file2.csv:

```
ID, Phone, Email
1234680000000000, 123-456-7890, johnsmith@test.com
```

I know I'm way off, but this may give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish...

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

pandas.read_csv('file1.csv', dtype=np.float64)
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df.round(0)
df.to_csv(float_format='file2.csv')
```

Here is the error I receive:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJoOR.png)

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have shown?

Comment: Where should the digits `468` come from in the desired output?

Comment: There's no way to recover the precision lost by formatting your id as `.2e`. You could assign the remaining digits sequentially for all records that have the same I'd, but you still need to decide how you're going to make those up, and accept the risk that the recovered ids could be different from the originals

Comment: I believe its trying to convert the whole file, which results in an error on the emails

Comment: File1 is what we start with, file2 is the desired output

Comment: How was this generated?  As others have said, if all you have is "1.23E+15", then there is simply no way to know that it should be 1234680000000000.  You can't "invent" digits that aren't there.

Comment: I understand what you're asking, but it's scientific notation which seems to be a calculation Python, Pandas, etc. can handle. If I can convert 1.23E+15 to 1234680000000000 using Python and Pandas, why can't the entire column be converted?

Answer (score 0):

The text in your CSV file, "1.23E+15", means "one-point-two-three, raised to the 15th power"... that's all Python, Pandas, anything (but you) can know about that number.

I say "but you", because you seem to know that before "1.23E+15", there was the value 1234680000000000.

But, then some other program/process chopped off the "46800..." part and all it left was "1.23E+15"—something *decreased the precision* of the original value.

That's why @TimRoberts asked "How was this generated?"  To get back 1234680000000000, you need to go to the program/process that last had that higher-precision value and try to change that program/process to **not decrease the precision of the number**.